# My regex will not work if applied to a multiline xml schema

Tags: regex, xml, schema

I've written a regex to alter some XML nodes - taking a generic node name and replacing it instead with the nodes attribute value like so:
Regex

```
<custom-attribute attribute-id="(.*)?"\s*(>*)(.*?)</custom-attribute>
```

for the following xml:

```
<custom-attribute attribute-id="isNewtest">false</custom-attribute>
```

using replace regex

```
<$1>$3</$1>
```

gives output of

```
<isNewtest>false</isNewtest>
```

which is what I am looking for - however - once more than one node is introduced into the schema - e.g

```
<custom-attribute attribute-id="isNewtest">false</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="isAnotherNewtest">false</custom-attribute>
```

and I run the regex, the output is:

```
<isNewtest">false</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="isAnotherNewtest>false</isNewtest">false</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="isAnotherNewtest>
```

which is not what I was expecting, I was hoping for:

```
<isNewtest>false</isNewtest>
<isAnotherNewtest>false</isAnotherNewtest>
```

I'm obviously missing something to do with searching through more than one node at a time or multiline selector? - Can someone point me in the right direction please? I've got to restructure a 20,000 line xml doc and not relishing the idea of doing it manually line by line..

Comment: This is one of the reasons why parsing XML should be done with the dedicated parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was being blind, this works

```
<custom-attribute attribute-id="(.*?)"\s*(>)(.*?)</custom-attribute>
```